# Can I use a Freepik icon as my commercial mobile app icon?

Tags: icon, copyright, applications

I know Freepik icons may not be used as logo types, but logos and icons are two different things. I have a mobile app that I intend to sell, can I use an icon from Freepik and use it as the app icon?

Note: I get Freepik icons from falticon.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dead set on this workflow idea, then either use the free license and clearly attribute it not being your work or pay the minor fee to get full license - see screencap below.

[image]

That said, it's a *lousy* business model idea for you to do so on several fronts: it marks you as unprofessional in that you're having to use someone else's work and having to attribute, or you pay the license fee and get a generic as hell icon for your app icon; it reflects poorly on your creativity and/or long-term vision to be using lowest-cost, lowest specificity/stock icon resources versus either paying a real designer and giving them a specific brief and engaging in that process or designing it yourself to the best of your abilities; it also marks you as fly-by-night - the kind of developer who is here today, and will not be here next week to support their app.

I'd suggest strongly that you consider hiring a designer, paying them decently, and engaging in a full process - or if you already *have* an in-house designer, assigning a project to them of the app icon design, designating enough *real budget and **time*** to them to do a decent job, and again, engaging with the process.

Comment: Why unprofessional? I sometime consider mentioning all free tools and services I used for building the app, as a way for thanking them.

Comment: One more thing, app icons and logos are two very different things, right?
So I don't have to redesign the icon or change it to make it different, as ordered in the image you provided, because app icon is not logo.

Comment: Fisher, understood: no worries if you're globally good at attributions; however consider that unless your app is super-low-cost or freeware, it sends a bargain-basement message if you're charging real money for something which shows minimal investment from you monetarily. I *know* you will have poured hours and heart and soul into code, UX and the UI, but that's *invisible investment* to most users - they *expect* a certain level of design and UX as the minimal acceptable standard, so they don't see what that cost you in effort; visibly cheaping out AND charging money can feel exploitative.

Comment: @fisher you might have problems if you need to print this on a fork for example

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for you when you download a graphic from Freepik they have a screen that tells you what you need to do to give proper attribution to the content's creator.

[image]

In your case, you need to click the ***How to attribute the author for other media***? link.

You are then shown a new window where you need to navigate to the ***Apps/Games***.

[image]

Follow the instructions and you are on your way!

Here is their FAQ about using elements in Apps/Games.

> - Can I use Freepik's images on my App/Game/Video which I intend to sell?
>
> This is permitted as long as you comply with the policies regarding
>   the use of our resources which include using these as secondary
>   elements of your design, the non-redistribution of our resources and
>   credit to the author if you’re not a Premium member.

So depending on the graphic you have to attribute it correctly or if the designer doesn't allow attribution you need to buy a [Freepik Premium Plan Here](https://www.freepik.com/profile/preagreement/getstarted).